# Gui created in pycharm is not running?

Tags: python, tkinter

Failed to execute script pyi_rth_tkinter

I created a gui in pycharm and install through pyinstaller n it shows successfull but whenever i try to open it pops out message like this. As i am very new in coding please help me**
from tkinter import *

```
root  = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.title("Barcode finder")

dict = {"206621":["nescafe red mug solubale coffee 100gr","7616100997329","nestle", "25aed"]}

def barcode():
    x = e.get()
    value = dict.get(x)

    if value:
        decision.configure(text = value)

    else:
        decision.configure(text = "barocde not found")

mylabel = Label(root, text = "Enter barcode", fg = "red", bg ="blue", padx = 40 , pady = 20)
mylabel.pack()

e = Entry(root, width= 20, )
e.pack()

mylabel2 = Button(root, text = "Submit", padx = 10, pady = 10, command = barcode)
mylabel2.pack ()

decision = Label(root, text = "", font =("Ariel Bold", 10))
decision.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Without any code its hard to say what is wrong, please include your code, there could by thousands of reasons as to why this happened

Comment: Last login: Fri Sep 18 21:53:48 on ttys000
Apples-MacBook-Pro-7:~ apple$ /Users/apple/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/dist/gui ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller/hooks/rthooks/pyi_rth__tkinter.py", line 20, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: Tcl data directory "/var/folders/tb/9brj7r7n7650rkn9v765330r0000gn/T/_MEIhDWRUc/tcl" not found.
[5421] Failed to execute script pyi_rth__tkinter
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
[Process completed]

Comment: the code is below

Comment: Try this `pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Tk':'tk' --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Tcl':'tcl' your_script.py`

Comment: it work perfectly bro thanks you so much. God bless you a lot but can you explain why i have to use this one bro

Comment: It should be run on terminal and make sure to replace `your_script.py`  with your script name

Comment: brother it worked perfectly but can you explain me little bit as i am new to coding about a week only and i m trying to make simple project to get promotion in my company

Comment: brother can i have your whatsapp number please so that i can contact you if i have need your help please or your email

Comment: Ive added an answer. And its not ideal to give personal information off like this. If you insist i can give you a chat link though

Comment: Can you give me a link to chat

Comment: Yes it worked  how to accept it

Comment: I have accept the answer

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221803/custom try to join this room

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this pyinstaller code for your tkinter code to work for macOS.

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Tk':'tk' --add-binary='/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Tcl':'tcl' your_script.py
```

This is how it is in macOS, you just have to do these.

Hope this helped

Comment: it worked but one more question how i can i edit my app in future if i want to add or delete data in my app

Comment: Bro thank yoy very very much. God bless you and i wish for your success life ahead

Comment: @BigGame Would appreciate if you could mark this as an answer. Take a look here (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: if i want to put image in my code where should i input

Comment: Actually this is my first gui so i just want i complete it and this is first time i have ever created a app .

Comment: brother the gui app runs but every time i open the gui the terminal also apperas

Comment: still same result

Comment: Using `-w` will get rid of the terminal bro

Comment: pyinstaller: error: ambiguous option: --add- could match --add-data, --add-binary it shows like that

Comment: @BigGame Im so sorry. that was a typo, ive updated again, just copy paste

Comment: bro still the terminal gets open and if i close the terminal the app gets closed too

Comment: I have no idea why its like that now, try deleting the old exe(also `dist`,`build` and `spec` file) and then make a new exe again, also try replacing `w` with `--windowed`. Its the same, but still give it a try

Comment: I will try brother