# building with Pyinstaller not working on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyinstaller

I have had some errors working while with pyinstaller for python 3. I am using Mac OS Catalina. please help me my issue.

```
print("Hello World")
```

I'm running the below pyinstaller

```
pyinstaller --log-level=DEBUG --clean --icon "/Users/projects/hello/build/noun_wooden_wheel_2216564_420.icns" --name hello_world --exclude-module='FixTk' --exclude-module='tcl' --exclude-module='tk' --exclude-module='_tkinter' --exclude-module='tkinter' --exclude-module='Tkinter' --exclude-module='pytest' --onefile -d all --windowed main.py
```

**Here is the error I get after I run the output file**

```
Error loading Python lib '/var/folders/q9/g1d15sw13q5cdspzvpq46mrr0000gn/T/_MEIgYpRBc/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/var/folders/q9/g1d15sw13q5cdspzvpq46mrr0000gn/T/_MEIgYpRBc/Python, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/folders/q9/g1d15sw13q5cdspzvpq46mrr0000gn/T/_MEIgYpRBc/Python: code signature invalid for '/var/folders/q9/g1d15sw13q5cdspzvpq46mrr0000gn/T/_MEIgYpRBc/Python'

    /var/folders/q9/g1d15sw13q5cdspzvpq46mrr0000gn/T/_MEIgYpRBc/Python: stat() failed with errno=3
```

I'm not even able to run on the machine I built it on.

Comment: Make sure to use flags that your well aware of ONLY. Why do you need `--log-level=DEBUG` and `--clean` and take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63960218/gui-created-in-pycharm-is-not-running/63960917#63960917) for macOS

Comment: thanks for replying but even after removing those it made no difference. I also tried to follow the other post you shared.

To me the error seems something to do with code signing?

Comment: Its all mac related issue, i think you will be getting one of these either ways, try googling, alot of solutions come up at github

Answer (score 0):

macOS does not understand one-file bundles, do not use the `--onefile` flag.

Comment: Thanks Richard
Actually even if I leave that flag out it made no difference. 

It seems to be complaining about code signing in the error message

code signature invalid for '/var/folders/q9/g1d15sw13q5cdspzvpq46mrr0000gn/T/_MEIgYpRBc/Python'

    /var/folders/q9/g1d15sw13q5cdspzvpq46mrr0000gn/T/_MEIgYpRBc/Python: stat() failed with errno=3